# Error while installing package in ASP.NET core app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, sendgrid, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 to create ASP.NET Core Web app. While installing Sendgrid package, I am getting following error.

> Package Sendgrid 8.0.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Sendgrid 8.0.5 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 supports:
>   net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=wp8+netcore45+net45+wp81+wpa81)
>   Package SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client 3.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.`

Any solution for this error?

Comment: Could you please post your project.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use the pre-release version.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid.NetCore/

Answer (score 1):

The error gives you this support matrix for SendGrid 8.0.5 and its dependencies.

```
                                net     net45   portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81
SendGrid                         1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client            1             1
SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client      1
```

You can see that none of them support the Core Framework (`netcoreapp`) and instead require the Full Framework (`net`).

If you require your app to run on the Core Framework, you cannot use SendGrid 8.0.5. Your options include (but are not limited to) using `SendGrid.NetCore` or using `MailKit`.

If you do not require your app to run on the Core Framework and are okay supporting only the Full Framework (`net`), then you can use SendGrid 8.0.5.

For our own apps, we've elected to use `MailKit` version `1.10.0`, because it is more mature than `SendGrid.NetCore` is and it supports the Core Framework. We use it as follows:

project.json

```
"dependencies": {                                                        
    "MailKit": "1.10.0"                                                  
},                                                                       
"frameworks": {                                                          
    "netcoreapp1.1": {}                                                  
}
```

Send an email using SendGrid with MailKit.

```
var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Admin", "admin@mailbox.com"));
mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Jon Doe", "jon@doe.com"));
mimeMessage.Subject = "An Email for You!";
mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("html")
{
    Text = "This is the message.";
};

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
    client.Connect("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync("myuser@foobar.com", "ASD43234GDX");    
    await client.SendAsync(mimeMessage);
    client.Disconnect(true);  
}
```